# What could be causing the primary key exception?

Tags: sql-server, exception, primary-key

My ASP pages store session variables in SQL Server with the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyProcedure]
        @sessionId varchar(512),
        @variable varchar(350),
        @value image
AS
BEGIN   
        BEGIN TRAN
                DECLARE @result int = 0;
                DECLARE @locked bit;

                IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sessions WHERE id = @sessionId) = 0
                BEGIN
                        SET @result = -1;
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                        DELETE Variables WHERE sessionId = @sessionId AND variable = @variable
                        IF @value IS NOT NULL
                        BEGIN
                                INSERT Variables VALUES(@sessionId, @variable, @value, 0)
                        END                                                  
                END    
    COMMIT TRAN
    RETURN @result
END
```

But once in a while, I get a primary key exception (Msg 2627): "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Variables'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Variables'". 
Note: There are no triggers involved.

Thanks!

Comment: can we have structure of the table Variables? Is your Variables Primary key autoincremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your PK is on `sessionId,variable` then concurrent executions of the stored procedure with the same `@sessionId,@variable` could do this.

Both execute the

```
DELETE Variables WHERE sessionId = @sessionId AND variable = @variable
```

line concurrently and then both proceed to the `insert`.

This could only occur if there is no pre-existing record with the `sessionId,variable` combination as then the `DELETE`s would block.

Comment: But the BEGIN/COMMIT doesn't prevent this? If not, how do I lock the record (without having to lock the entire table)? Thanks for your time

Comment: @JorgitoGutierrez - When the record doesn't exist there's nothing to lock. You would need `serializable` isolation level or equivalent locking hints to lock the range but what is wrong with the current behaviour? If you have 2 concurrent executions with the same `sessionid,variable` it is going to be quite arbitrary which one "wins" anyway so why not just let the loser raise a PK violation rather than blocking it so it immediately overwrites the other execution?

Comment: I'm confused now on how to implement the solution... I've never worked with serializable isolation. What if I do a "SELECT * FROM WHERE sessionId = @sessionId AND variable = @variable". Will it help locking the data (if it doesn't exists)?

Comment: @JorgitoGutierrez - I wouldn't run the whole thing under `serializable`. Just adding `HOLDLOCK` to the `DELETE` statement should be sufficient to lock that range. i.e. `DELETE Variables WITH(HOLDLOCK)  WHERE sessionId = @sessionId AND variable = @variable`